# Unable to select and modify or delete a segue on Visual Studio 2012, Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm unable to select a segue in order to delete it, name it, or update it. 
Using Xamarin.iOS latest version and Visual Studio 2012

Comment: You need to provide more information, screenshots, steps that you have tried, etc...

Comment: Understand however, I can't think of any other way of describing it. I created a classic Xamarin.iOS project on Visual Studio 2012. When I go to the storyboard and add more view controllers and link them with segues, there's nothing I can do with those segues. I cannot click on them in order to update their identifier name, or delete them or anything. They are there, they work, however there's nothing i can do to modify them. I sent an email to Xamarin support, and their response was, "click on it and then hit delete.".

Comment: I'm able to click and edit segues of the Iphone storyboard, but not the ipad storyboard. When creating the project it actually created two storyboards, one for iphone and one for Ipad.

Comment: And after closing and reopening Visual studio it works now.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue: In my case I am unable to select a segue when the storyboard is zoomed in or out.

Either zoom back in or out to 100% (no indication in the designer for that) or reopen your storyboard.

Comment: Zooming to 100%, bizarre solution but does work for me! Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, So what i found works is if you go to the top of your Story board screen, make sure that the view as is set to Generic because mine was for iphone and once changing to Generic, all was good to go.

I hope this helped.